# Use document interaction to transfer IAP's between my two apps

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have two similar apps with in-app-purchase (IAP) content that could be shared between them.  I'd like to reward customers who buy in one app, by letting them transfer the purchase to the other app.  However, I'm worried that my apps would be rejected due to the App Store review guideline that says you can't have any non-App store content activation methods.

As far as technical feasibility, it's clear to me that the [Document Interaction mechanism](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1) is a means to this end (sans web server).  I can have each app register a custom file type.  The app in which the user purchased the content can show a link to launch the other app, passing it appropriate metadata as the "launched file" so the second can then mark the items as purchased.

Does anybody know if this has been attempted, and if Apple is approving such an approach?

Note that I'm not concerned about purchase security with this approach, because making paying customers happy is much more important to me than preventing piracy.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an answer to the precise question above as it is a useful alternate technique of accomplishing the end goal.  If you set things up correctly, two apps can share KeyChain access, and thus share metadata about purchased IAPs. This requires using the same Bundle Seed ID (e.g. "AXGUKHGX...") for the app ID, in combination with setting things up properly in your app's info plist.  This latter technique is a much more elegant approach for propagating sharable IAPs.